# How to resolve this new AWS Lightsail and AWS EC2 t2large 502 gateway error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, timeout, instance, gateway

My website is ecommerce Multivendor WordPress website. Website is under developent.
Hosting is AWS Lightsail and now I changed EC2 also.

From last 6days to till date, I am facing 502 Gateway error but in my localhost it's working Good. Localhost i am using Xampp.

After facing this issue, I upgrade my Instance from 2gb ram into 8gb ram for lightsail also In EC2 i am using t2large 8gb ram, 30gb ssd.

I added this error log file. [Tue Nov 19 07:36:15.618339 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2823:tid 139953883195136] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 127.0.0.1:47644] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)...